# Compute logarithm of nonzero values in a tensor with keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a custom loss function and it requires taking logarithm of  values in the output tensor from the model. The tensor may contain zeros as well and so I want to take only non-zero values and compute logarithm.

The output tensor is of shape (20,224,224). I could get the number of nonzero elements along axis 0 using the below function.

```
#To get the number of nonzero elements along the axis 0                
count = K.tf.count_nonzero(y,axis=0)
```

But I couldn't understand how to calculate the nonzero log. I could come up with numpy solution as below but not sure about it's keras equivalent.

```
loss = np.log2(y, out=np.zeros_like(y), where=(y!=0))
```

Can someone help me with calculating logarithm of non zeros along axis 0 for the tensor.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach might leverage:

```
tf.where(
    condition,
    x=None,
    y=None,
    name=None
)
```

and related functions listed:  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf
that are similar to the numpy versions you are exploring.

For example, you might consider something like using the above tf.where() function to test for zero entries and either select from the original tensor (x), or a similar shaped tensor of "ones" depending on the result.  Then, you can compute the *log* of the resulting tensor and do the final summation over that result etc.

The below is an example using Colab with Eager execution that shows the idea a bit more explicitly.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

# Above only works in Google Colab.
# Also, note eager execution is default True for Tensorflow 2.0

import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.Variable([[2.0],[0.0],[0.0],[3.0],[4.0]])
y_pred = tf.Variable([[2.0],[-1.0],[1.0],[3.0],[4.0]])

def my_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):

    print('y_true:')
    print(y_true)
    print('y_pred:')
    print(y_pred)

    y_zeros = tf.zeros_like(y_pred)
    print('y_zeros:')
    print(y_zeros)

    y_mask = tf.math.greater(y_pred, y_zeros)
    print('y_mask:')
    print(y_mask)

    res = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, y_mask)
    print('res:')
    print(res)

    logres = tf.math.log(res)
    print('logres:')
    print(logres)

    finres = tf.math.reduce_sum(logres)
    print('finres:')
    print(finres)

    return finres

myres = my_loss_function(y_true, y_pred)
print(myres)
```

I hope this helps.